# sudo command no longer works in my applescript

Tags: terminal, passwords, applescript, sleep, sudo

*2023 9/27 **edit**:*
if anyone knows how to configure Gordon Davisson's answer with Touch ID, that would fully resolve this post.

*2023 9/9 **original** post:*
why might this not be working anymore?
did something change with background Terminal password prompting?

for a few months now, I've used a script to put my macbook to sleep. I normally have sleep disabled so that I can close the lid without stopping anything or locking anything.

this worked fine until today. I now receive :
'sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required'

previously the script was able to trigger a user prompt itself, and I had that set to allow fingerprint authorization. so I could simply activate the script, touch the touch sensor, and be on my way.

the full script is :

```
do shell script "sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0"

tell application "System Events" to sleep

do shell script "sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1"
```

and is wrapped as an app in my Applications folder.

I tried using `sudo -S pmset` but that seems to be for piping in the password from somewhere else or some other kind of prompt.
I believe that's the wrong thing because I want it to do what it did before.
which I think was prompting through the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how using `sudo` this way would ever have worked. In any case, the better way to run shell code as root from AppleScript is to use `with administrator privileges` instead of `sudo`:

```
do shell script "pmset -a disablesleep 0" with administrator privileges

tell application "System Events" to sleep

do shell script "pmset -a disablesleep 1" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: do you know how to authorize this with touch?

Comment: without touch, this won't function well enough for the larger application of this script.

Comment: Do you have touch ID enabled for unlocking your Mac? I think that also controls whether it can work for this.

Comment: yes I have touch activated for the main unlocking. I think to get the old script to work, I added touch as sufficient for sudo in the pam.d folder. but I'm not sure what this new method would be under. or if it could be done the same way.